# Why are queries not being logged?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got an enviroment set on Dev that should keep a log with every query ran, but it's not writing anything. I'm using the slow-log feature for it...

These are my thresholds on the elasticsearch.yml:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qfwnruhD

And this is my whole logging.yml:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aXg8xHNE

I'm using ElasticSearch 1.3.1 in this enviroment.

Comment: So, have you tried setting index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 0ms , and restarting elasticsearch. ?

Comment: Did so, "0ms", "0", "1ms" http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qfwnruhD

Comment: ok, so verify if your yml file is ok or not..

Comment: Both ymls are both pasted on the question, they seem to be working since the instance is running ok and the instance logs are being printed correctly (Not the slow logs).

Comment: Here's an article explaining how to monitor search queries using Packetbeat: https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-the-search-queries

Answer (score 0):

You should set the threshold to 0ms if you want to log all queries. On a smaller index I was testing on, lots of queries were taking less than 1ms.

If that doesn't work, perhaps elasticsearch isn't using the config file you are updating.

Comment: I've tried every combination of thresholds. The config thing... I guess it could happen, however at some point I "broke" the yml just to check whether the error would be spotted by the launching elasticsearch instance and it seemed so, I don't have many more ideas on this and it's driving me crazy.